# Adding an entry to a python tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples representing x,y points. I also have a list of values for each of these points. How do I combine them into a list of lists (i.e one entry for each point [x,y,val]) or a list of tuples?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't add entries to tuples, since tuples are immutable. But you can create a new list of lists:

```
new = [[x, y, val] for (x, y), val in zip(points, vals)]
```

Comment: Thanks ephes, just what I was looking for

Comment: Use (x, y, val) if you want the result to still be a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable, they can't be modified. Convert it to a list, then convert it back if you want to (list((a, b))).