# Adding a constant tuple value to a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples (each tuple item is a pair of integers) and I would like to add a constant value to each tuple in the list.

For example
[(x0,y0),(x1,y1),...] -> [(x0+xk,y0+yk),(x1+xk,y1+yk)....]

xk,yk are constants

How do I do this

Thanks

Comment: and what do you mean with add? add as in "add a third item" or add as in "add to every first (and/or second) item"?

Comment: you have a similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282300/adding-an-entry-to-a-python-tuple.  If its another new problem, show what you have and any errors you encountered that doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>>> l = [(1,2), (3,4)]
>>>> for i, e in enumerate(l):
....     l[i] = (e[0]+xk, e[1]+yk)
```

As always, untested. ;-)

If you don't need to do it in place, it's even simpler

```
>>>> l = [(e[0]+xk, e[1]+yk) for e in l]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [numpy](https://numpy.org/), e.g.,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[2,3]])
>>> print a
[[1 2]
 [2 3]]
>>> print a + 2
[[3 4]
 [4 5]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't add a constant to a tuple because tuples are immutable.

You can however create a new tuple from the old one by incrementing it's values. See jae's answer for the basics of how to do this.

You should note however that you will be creating a lot of new tuples in this loop and this may not be a very efficient way of handling this. You should investigate numpy (as suggested by nikow) or perhaps using lists or coordinate objects instead of tuples.

Comment: Thanks for providing the background info that I omitted. :-D  (Yes, I upvoted it too).

Answer (score 0):

an example to add things to tuple

```
>>> a=(1,2)
>>> a+=(1,)
>>> a
(1, 2, 1)
```

you can adapt it to your requirement

Comment: Even so, if you're planning on appending things, it may be advantageous to use a list rather than a tuple.

Comment: Hi ghostdog, sorry I was not more specific, I would like to add a constant value to every item in the tuple .ie [(x0,y0),(x1,y1),...] -> (x0+xk,y0+yk),(x1+xk,y1+yk)....]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
l = [(i[0]+k[0], i[1]+k[1]) for i in l]
```

Test code:

```
l = [(1,2), (3,4)]
k = (10, 100)
l = [(i[0]+k[0], i[1]+k[1]) for i in l]
assert l == [(11, 102), (13, 104)]
```